# Using useMappedState from Redux React Hooks, component not re-rendered after API response

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, redux-react-hook

[image]

`useMappedState` doesn't re-renders the component on receiving update from Ajax response
Below is my component in action. I have logged entries at various stages and attached the screenshot of a fresh single render

You can safely assume that redux part is working fine for reducers and actions as visible from console entries of salesPerfData inside mapState before and after response in expanded from

```
import React, { useCallback, useState, useEffect, memo } from 'react';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import StackedChart from '../../../components/StackedChart/index';
import { useDispatch, useMappedState } from 'redux-react-hook';
import { Creators } from './actions';

const SalesPerformance = ( ) => {
    const mapState = useCallback(
        (state) => { 
            console.log('inside mapSate', state);
            return { salesPerfData: state.salesPerfReducer.salesPerf } 
        },
        []
    );
    const { salesPerfData } = useMappedState(mapState);
    console.log('after useMappedState', salesPerfData);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(
        () => {
            dispatch(Creators.fetchSalesPerf({ filter: 'monthly', duration: 'last3' }))
        },
        []
    );

    return (
        <section>
            <Paper className='mTB30'>
                <Grid container>
                    <Grid item sm={12}>
                        <StackedChart config={salesPerfData}  />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </Paper>
        </section>
    );
};
export default SalesPerformance;
```

Sandbox link here - https://codesandbox.io/s/o490z3wwny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `mapState` function you have:

```
return { salesPerfData: state.salesPerfReducer.salesPerf }
```

but it should be:

```
return { salesPerfData: state.salesPerfReducer.salesPerfData }
```

salesPerf**Data** instead of salesPerf. Since `salesPerf` is not defined within `salesPerfReducer`, your `salesPerfData` variable remains undefined.

Fixing this results in some other errors that I assume are just due to the downstream code not yet being tested.

Comment: Argghhhh!  I'm making silly mistakes now. Thank you! I deleted the other question. It works for me. It fixed the issue for me what I wanted in actual project. We'll let go of the sandbox link.